# When does $\sum_n \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n^p} \right)^n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I know that this series diverges when $p \geq 1$, since $(1 - \frac{1}{n})^n \rightarrow e^{-1}$. What about when $p < 1$?

Comment: I think the series is divergent in all cases. $\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{n^p}\right)^{n^p}\right]^{1/n^p}$.  Then $\left(1-\frac{1}{n^p}\right)^{n^p} \to e^{-1}$.

Comment: @kmitov How about $p=0$?

Comment: Is the case $p=0$ a big problem?

Comment: For $0 < p < 1$, we have $$
\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n^p }}} \right)^n  \sim \exp \left( { - n^{1-p}} \right)
$$ which shows convergence. When $p=0$, all terms are $0$, thus the series converges trivially. For $p<0$, it clearly diverges.

Comment: @kmitov I just illustrated that your claim "I think the series is divergent in all cases." is false.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133866/discussion-between-kmitov-and-gary).

Comment: @kmitov Use a Taylor polynomial for the logarithm:
$$
\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n^p }}} \right)^n  = \exp \left( {n\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n^p }}} \right)} \right) = \exp \left( {n\left( { - \frac{1}{{n^p }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^{2p} }}} \right)} \right)} \right) = \exp \left( { - n^{1 - p}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {n^{1 - 2p} } \right)} \right).
$$ This is more precise than what I wrote. The error term may be large but the decay is controlled by $- n^{1 - p}$ for large $n$.

Comment: In fact, $$
\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n^p }}} \right)^n  = \exp \left( {n\log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{n^p }}} \right)} \right) = \exp \left( {n\left( { - \frac{1}{{n^p }} - \frac{1}{{2n^{2p} }} -  \cdots } \right)} \right) \le \exp ( - n^{1 - p} ).
$$

Comment: Thank you!  My calculations were wrong.